# Writing a rake task to send daily emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, rake

I'm really new to rails. I'm trying to learn how to write a cron job with a rake task to send daily digest emails. How should I go about doing this?

I'm guessing that I write a loop in the task to go through each user and compile and email. Then I send it inside the for loop.

How do I set this rake task as a cron job so that it runs in the background? This seems like it should be super simple, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, as you've visualized already, is to define a rake task which would run at a scheduled time. Crontab is best for that if you're on a Linux system. Following are the steps you would follow to do that:

1. The rake task with the logic of fetching the emails to send digest emails.
2. A shell script, `digest.sh` which would load up and run the rake task. Something like this:

`cd /your/app /usr/bin/rake utils:sendNotifications > /your/app/log/notifications.log`

We're telling it to go into your application folder ( /your/app ), run the rake task `utils:sendNotifications` and log the output in `log/notifications.log`

3. And finally, [schedule tasks](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/schedule_tasks_on_linux_using_crontab/) on Linux [using crontab](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Comment: Awesome. Will these rake tasks run in the background by default?

Comment: Yes. The rake is instantiated, run and done with on schedule.

Comment: is is better to use queue in rake to send emails ? Because when my loop will gather 300 mails to send it could be a problem i guess...